# Unicode math and double factorial

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, tex-gyre-math, math-fonts

I must confess that the details of font usage and related packages are pretty fuzzy to me.  That said, I am under the impression that to use the TeX Gyre fonts, my document must look like the following (compile with lualatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setromanfont{Tex Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}
\[(2n)!!\]
\end{document}
```

My question is regarding the appearance of the double factorial in the above.  With the preamble removed, the double factorial appears as I would hope, but has extra(?) spacing in the document above.  I can manually correct for the spacing, but then if I change fonts the spacing is off again.  Why does the spacing change and is it possible to get the desired spacing without manual intervention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

classically `!` is `mathclose` but unicode math sets it as `mathpunct` which makes two adjacent ones have `\thinmuskip` between them. You can use `{!}{!}` to avoid that.

Unicode has a !! character which `unicode-math` makes available as `\Exclam` but unfortunately it's not in this font, the log shows

```
Missing character: There is no ‼ (U+203C) in font TeXGyreTermesMath:mode=base;
```

Comment: Thanks, `{!}{!}` fixes the spacing.  Out of curiosity, is there an argument to be made for whether `mathclose` or `mathpunct` is the appropriate classification?

Comment: in math `!` is pretty much only used for factorial so mathclose probably works better although it isn't really a mathclose in the sense of `)`  I'll complain to Will. see what happens:-)

Comment: @ScottH. raised as https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/350